# Simplify table view in SQL 2012

Tags: sql

My SQL query is giving results as below:

```
Account_Id  LCD         LPD
125469      26/09/2011  NULL
125469      NULL        11/08/2014
125469      NULL        NULL
```

However i would like to put the above result in one line, any help will be appreciated:

```
Account_Id  LCD         LPD
125469      26/09/2011  11/08/2014
```

Comment: What are the conditions to define which value needs to be returned if there are multiple `LCD`/`LPD` values for the same `Account_Id`? The most recent date?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Account_Id,
       MAX(LCD),
       MAX(LPD)
FROM Test 
GROUP BY Account_Id
```